# Looking for an example of how to use ServiceStack.OrmLite to auto gen Entities from an existing SQL Server Schema

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I see that ServiceStack.OrmLite Lite has [this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/pull/68/files).

I feel like something is not sinking in with this statement from ServiceStack,

problem with Code-Gen DTO's changes breaks code, ihibits DRY forces abstraction, mutiple versions in parallel implementations

Seems to me that it means using full ORM with SS instead of a micro orm would be doing exactly this or am I way off here? I am not really sure since I auto-gen the entities but hand code the dto's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote was about Code-Gen DTO's, e.g. like the development workflow WCF/SOAP encourages when you use **Add Service Reference** dialog or `svcutil.exe` to generate a client proxy.

This has nothing to do with Code-First ORMs and Data Models that OrmLite promotes.